# How to Audit for Access with Cross Database Ownership Chaining

Tags: sql-server

I've just joined the data team of a new company and we have a large SQL Server environment (100+ instances) and cross database ownership chaining is on by what I gather is a necessity. I'm looking for 3rd party tools or even scripts for some way to audit potential access to a database including the potential of cross-database ownership chaining. Does anyone know of any way to accomplish this, or any products that do the same sort of thing?

I have mostly 2008 R2 and some 2012 instances; there may be one or two 2005 machines but they can be safely ignored. Most are Enterprise Edition although some might be Standard Edition.

Comment: Are you just looking to find out which databases and/or instances have this set?

Comment: No, I don't think so; I apologize if I'm a little hazy on the overall concepts, but the idea is to ascertain, bearing in mind what instances/dbs have this enabled, who could have potential access to an object/database both directly, and as a potential access through, say, creating a stored procedure on another database using cross database ownership chaining.

Comment: What version(s) of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @SQLRockstar, [op reports] I have mostly 2008R2 and some 2012 instances...there may be 1 or 2 2005 machines but they can be safely ignored. EDIT: Enterprise Edition mostly as well. May be some Standard.

Comment: I don't know of any scripts to accomplish this, but SQL Secure from Idera mentions the ability to evaluate cross database chaining. http://www.idera.com/SQL-Server/SQL-secure/

Comment: Thanks, I talked to the idera folks, and their products came reasonably close but not quite what I'm looking for.  Might have to do this more manually.  Thanks again for the lead though!